# Hide android toolbar on scroll of CoordinatorLayout but keep TabLayout fixed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have the following layout file
`activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/toolbar_icon"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_grid_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/content_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/sliding_tabs"/>

            <com.ili.view.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Expected behavior:

[image]

I would like the latter to show when I open the app, and the toolbar to hide upon scrolling.

But with my `activity_main.xml` I am getting the following behavior:

[image]

And after scrolling down, the toolbar hides(as expected) and the `SlidingTabLayout` shows.
But I would like my tab layout to remain fixed below the view pager.

Now I know that this may be because I'm setting the behavior of the whole drawer layout to `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, so I tried to separate the `SlidingTabLayout` and put it outside the drawer layout and it worked as expected, except that the `SlidingTabLayout` stayed over the last row of the list in my `ViewPager`, since in `CoordinatorLayout` I cannot tell `DrawerLayout` to remain on top of my `SlidingTabLayout`.

So anyone knows how I can make the toolbar hide upon scrolling but with my `SlidingTabLayout` to remain fixed and not hide the last row of the list?

Comment: Do you find the solution yet ? I have the same issue as yours.

Comment: @徐博俊 No sorry, we ended up keeping it fixed. Please share if you find a solution.